# CRM 2011 Rollup 12 Javascript errors

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, rollup, xrm

We recently upgraded to rollup 12 and we are now experiencing JavaScript errors being thrown whenever a grid related ribbon is presented containing ribbon customization the dialog message is stating a "Syntax Error" on line ~60 million of an internal CRM resource. This seems to only happen with customized ribbons (customized using the Ribbon workbench).

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, any tips for resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a bit of debugging we found that the issue was caused by the customized ribbon. We had a button we added to the ribbon that was calling into a javascript library. What was left off was the $webresource directive.

Hopefully this helps someone, the errors thrown for this do not help debug the root cause.

[Web Resources for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309473.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We had a custom button (created via ribbon workbench) with an enable rule that used JavaScript.

It worked correctly in the web client but would throw errors in Outlook.

This was because Outlook was refreshing the ribbon and not providing the `Xrm.Page.ui` object.

In the end we had to wrap all our enable rules with a check to see if it was defined.

e.g.

```
if(Xrm.Page.ui !== undefined) {
   //Do some work
}
```

Comment: After quite a bit of debugging we found that the issue was caused by the customized ribbon. We had a button we added to the ribbon that was calling into a javascript library. What was left off was the $webresource directive.